# Does python no longer overwrite py.exe with every update?

Tags: python, windows

I just installed Python 3.8.5 parallel to 3.8.3, but py.exe was not updated and remains 3.8.3. Is this no longer a feature? I also noticed that 3.8.3 is for some reason located at the top of my C: drive, while 3.8.5 got installed into AppData/Local, so maybe I did something wrong when installing 3.8.3?

Comment: You installed one "for all users" in C:\, and the other for "just yourself" in AppData/Local

Comment: Ah, yes, that. Does that effect py.exe?

Comment: A standard user installation won't upgrade the launcher if it's installed for all users, since that would require administrator access. If you uninstall the launcher, you can reinstall it just for the current user if you prefer that. IIRC, the per-user installation directory is "%LocalAppData%\Programs\Python\Launcher", which the installer adds to the user `PATH`.